# How to move objects between buckets on Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, bucket

Newbie here, I apologize for my ignorance.

I have 2 buckets on google cloud platform. Each bucket has folders with objects in those folders.

/bucket2/cloud-backup-archive/4-media set/object

/bucket/cloud-backup/4-media set/object

I want to move all the objects from the bucket2 named directories to the bucket named directories.

I have tried using transfer on the console and that doesn't work as it doesn't allow me to drill down to the directories.  It seems to only allow the contents of a bucket to be transffered.

Thank you for the help.

Kevin

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible ways to [move the specific objects from one bucket to another](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/renaming-copying-moving-objects#move) is to use `gsutil`.

To move all objects from specific subdirectory in `bucket2` to specific subdirectory in `bucket`, use the following command:

```
gsutil mv "gs://bucket2/cloud-backup-archive/4-media set/*" "gs:bucket/cloud-backup/4-media set/"
```

Note if you have a large amount of objects you might want to use `gsutil -m mv` option to perform a multi-threaded/multi-processing move.